# Python Heroku app has 0 web dynos despite right Procfile and at right location

Tags: python, heroku, procfile

I deployed python app successfully but when I open the app it is showing me:

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
Heroku logs --tail

here is my heroku logs:

> service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>   2018-09-20T10:05:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
>   2018-09-20T10:19:34.769300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc=**"No web processes running**" method=GET path="/"
>   host=demoaap.herokuapp.com request_id=1ae
>   01895-963b-4211-9b30-d16de606c827 fwd="182.72.121.210" dyno= connect=
>   service= s tatus=503 bytes= protocol=https

"heroku ps"commands gives:
No dynos on **demoaap** (demoaap is my app name)

moreover i have tried Herokuommand( " heroku ps:scale web=1" ) in order to run dynos but not working
.
Please help me out

Comment: What's in your `Procfile`? Are you using any web frameworks like Django or Flask?

Comment: "moreover i have tried Herokuommand( " heroku ps:scale web=1" ) in order to run dynos but not working "  Did you receive an error when you ran this command? If so, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a Procfile in deployment, make sure it does not have an extension such as `.txt`.  If it does, you might try:

1. Deleting that Procfile.txt.
2. Creating a new Procfile without the extension.
3. Pushing the new files to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 app:app

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Please take the time to explain it, to be even helpfuller for other users!